# DataFrame sort_values fails on a column containing both DateTimes and Dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I shall present the data that comes in, the relevant code that processes it, and the failure that results from that code attempting to process it.

Example data

```
symbol date                             open        high
       2023-09-11                  99.510002  101.940002
       2023-09-14 09:30:00-04:00         NaN         NaN
```

Example code

```
for d in data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False, na_position='last')['open']:
    print(d)
```

Example fails with

`TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`

I hate that basic python libs can't manage these minor juxtapositions. Treat date as 0:00, 23:59.999, allow configurations of such.

Does anyone know how to reasonably manage this without doing significant and expensive transformations to the underlying data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime and date objects cannot be compared directly, you should convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to have a common ground

Either do this explicitly (`data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`), or use the `key` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False, na_position='last', key=pd.to_datetime)
```